# handle consecutive connections from ios app to wamp server

Tags: ios, apache, connection, queue, wamp

I have an ios app that sends a command to a php script listening on a windows 2008server with wamp 2.5. If no response comes back in X seconds it sends back the command to the server. Each command contains also a session identifier.

The problem appears when the 2nd command sent to the server executes **before** the first. This way it **alters** the session identifier of the user that sent both commands, and when the 1st command tries to execute, it says the session id is incorrect.

Usually this scenario happens on peak moments when many users connect and thus the delay of the 1st command.

What is the proper way to handle these commands delays of the same user? Or queue them or manage them from apache?

Comment: This is a software development question. As such, I've flagged it for migration to StackOverflow. Please do not re- post there

Comment: @EEAA This question does not fit here either!

Comment: @RiggsFolly - this is absolutely a software development question. If not here, where do you propose that it fits?